# Case Specific Data in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I want to retrieve data which is having casespecific columns.
For example :

```
sel
col1(CASESPECIFIC),
col2 (CASESPECIFIC),
col3 (CASESPECIFIC),
col4 (CASESPECIFIC),
count(*) as cntt
from DB.tablename  
group by 1,2,3,4
```

Here, I have selected all the columns that are case specific.

So the results will include it all. But I was wondering if there is any other way to retrieve case specific data when there are millions of records. The above query will not be efficient in the case of millions of records.

PS: I'm executing this query in Teradata 15.10.1.4

Comment: Your question is really unclear.  What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Why do you think it's less efficient? Btw, when you always need case sensitive data you better define the column as `CASESPECEFIC`.